# A simple comparison with left and right stops working namespace std is not used

Tags: c++

There's a function in a .cpp file that looks like this:

```
void function() {
  //...
  if (left != right)
    do_something();
}
```

In an unrelated header file that ends up included in that .cpp file, there's this line:

```
using namespace std;
```

I was doing some cleanups and got rid of this `using namespace std` everywhere, and added the missing `std::` qualification. Yet the `if (left != right)` line doesn't compile anymore... what gives?

Answer (score 6):

Well: if they tell you that `using namespace std` is bad, they do mean it!

It turns out that the `left != right` was a comparison that was left from an older version of the code, which read

```
void function() {
  int left, right;
  //...
  if (left != right)
    do_something();
}
```

Later on, the code was refactored, and the `left` and `right` locals were removed.

**With `using namespace std`, the comparison was interpreted as `if (std::left != std::right)`, and was always true!** Because `std::left` and `std::right` are two functions, so they always compare different, and they can be compared because C++ inherits the, ahem, insanity of C, and treats functions like function pointers whenever necessary.

So yeah, if you're `using namespace std`, you should stop. Right now. It will happily make nonsensical code compile, without you ever knowing...

PVS-Studio can find such an error using the V1058 diagnostic: https://godbolt.org/z/YZTwhp (thank you Andrey Karpov!!).

Pinging cppcheck developers: you might wish to flag this one. It was a doozy.